# Através de um formulário - Obter a chave do celular

Tags: html5

Gostaria de saber se através de um formulário simples com html5 ,o usuário preenchia os campos ,e quando clicasse em enviar os dados pegasse o imei do celular ou alguma outra máscara...

A lógica seria para que ele não precisasse preencher estes campos (formulário) mais de uma vez... gostaria de saber se tem como e onde eu pudesse encontrar os caminhos das pedras...

Comment: então Diego, acredito que nem o imei ou coisa parecida tipo uma chave sei lá...estava vendo um video agora pouco,sobre cordova e tal eu não sei ainda o retorno que pode me dar a um longo prazo...Mas o fato é queria neste formulário simples,o usuário acessando e o background fizesse o trabalho por trás ...pra garantir algo que ele não preenchesse novamente o formulário...porque vai ser em massa entendeu?? essa é a questão...

Comment: se a ideia é armazenar os dados digitados para que o Usuario anonimo possa continuar o seu preenchimento depois, então acredito que terá de usar o [`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ou o [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via HTML, HTML5, JS ou qualquer outra linguagem/método por navegador, é **impossível**.

Via aplicação, usando o android studio, [aqui tem uma forma.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Obrigado!!! vou dar uma olhada.